# physical backup in mariadb 10.5 InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format

Tags: mariadb

I have mariadb 10.5 version 3 node galera cluster, on node 1 physical backup is running/working but on node 2 and 3 physical backup script is not working and getting error.....
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup --user=root --password=xxxx@123

error

2021-03-22  8:29:28 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.5.8.
[00] 2021-03-22 08:29:28 Error: cannot read redo log header

Can you please somebody suggest here what is going to wrong.